# How can the expression "as quickly as " be rewritten as noun expression?

Tags: adverbs

This is an example sentence:

> My old computer starts up as quickly as his latest computer.

I would like to rewrite this using the word "quickness".  My draft is:

> My old computer has as much quickness to start up as his latest computer.

Could anyone give me advice?

Comment: *...has the same boot time ...*

Comment: Is there some particular reason you want to use "quickness"?  It just isn't a very common word, and refers more to a general sense of speed than to anything specific, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My old computer's start-up speed is as good as his latest model.

"Quickness" is not very common in English (1997 instances in the Now corpus, against 274,242 of "speed"). It is usually used of people, often about their mental or conversational abilities. For most meanings of "quick", I would use "speed".

Answer (score 1):

My computers quickness at start-up matches that of the new computer he owns.

NB. in my opinion, this is not a very good word and would be better if it was replaced with 'speed' for example